# Flutter: Help building a scrollable ListView

Tags: flutter

item1, item2, item3 are all lists and i am trying to build a list view with all the items that each list holds, where all this three listview builders would take as much place as they need, lets say that item1 has 20 items in it and it will take 20 rows, and item2 has 25 etc. When i try to use a row and listview.builder it gives me an error. 
What I am trying to do:

```dart
body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(widget.item1[index]),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: widget.item1 == null ? 0 : widget.item1.length,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Among a huge list of crash report:

```dart
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on null.
```

The problem is that the only way I know is to make it with an `Expanded`, and it will divide the screen in three and make equal space or i can manipulate with flex, but this is not what i want.

```dart
body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(widget.item1[index]),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: widget.item1 == null ? 0 : widget.item1.length,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(widget.item2[index]),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: widget.item2 == null ? 0 : widget.item2.length,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(widget.item3[index]),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: widget.item3 == null ? 0 : widget.item3.length,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: why don't you use `SingleChildScrollView` + Column , and add your items programmatically before add as a children of your Column

Comment: @diegoveloper I was not aware of this, I am looking at it now.

Comment: you can use Slivers also, I have a question , item1,item2,item3 have the same type of objects?

Comment: Yes item1, item2, item3, are all list objects. Slivers are a little bit more advanced i suppose. But i can try slivers too.

Comment: yes I know, but item1, item2 , item3 have the same type of object?  List<Foo> item1 , List<Foo> item2 , List<Foo> item3 ? if it's true you can combine your lists

Comment: Yes all List<String>, can you elaborate, why should i combine the lists? I need the views to be separated.

Comment: oh ok, then  you use the first option I told you.

Comment: @diegoveloper please can you take a look at my answer because I don't understand what you mean  `and add your items programmatically before add as a children of your Column`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I was talking about, a `List` using `SingleChildScrollView` and `Column`, you can also do the same with `Slivers`

A sample I made for you:

```
 final List<String> item1 = List.generate(5, (val) => "item1 $val");
  final List<String> item2 = List.generate(5, (val) => "item2 $val");
  final List<String> item3 = List.generate(5, (val) => "item3 $val");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final items = <Widget>[];

    for (String i1 in item1) {
      items.add(ListTile(
        title: Text(i1),
      ));
    }

    for (String i2 in item2) {
      items.add(ListTile(
        title: Text(
          i2,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    for (String i3 in item3) {
      items.add(ListTile(
        title: Text(
          i3,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: items,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Another way using `ListView.builder` :

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(item1[index]),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: item1.length,
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      item2[index],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: item2.length,
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(item3[index]),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: item3.length,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Don't forget to check this awesome article about `Slivers` by Emily Fortuna (Flutter team)

https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f

Comment: I added another way using ListView.builder :) , It's better in terms of performance.

Comment: Thats even better, thank you very much, i really did learn something, cheers.